# SQL prompt to enter a letter that the last name starts with

Tags: sql, database, oracle

The whole question is: 
Rewrite the query so that the user is prompted to
enter a letter that the last name starts with. For example, if the user enters “H" (capitalized) when prompted for a letter, then the output should show all employees whose last name starts with the letter “H.”

```
SELECT last_name 
FROM employees
WHERE last_name like '%' = &Start_Letter
```

This wont work :(

Comment: Please identify the DBMS you're using.  'Prompting' is not normally something the DBMS does; it is something the client code does.  The notations for variables differ widely between DBMS.

Comment: its oracle database and this question is from the oracle database 11g fundamentals 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT last_name FROM employees WHERE last_name like '&Start_Letter%';
```

I have tested it in Oracle11g.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. :) Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT last_name  FROM employees WHERE last_name like &Start_Letter + '%';
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( i get this error: Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 55 but thanks

Comment: And what character do you have at column 55? It's a `&`... so apparently, your application is not translating `&Start_Letter` to something your DBMS understands...

Comment: Its oracle database if i do something like:SELECT  last_name, salary, department_id, employee_id
FROM employees
WHERE  manager_id = &enter_a_manager_id
ORDER BY employee_id; then &enter_a_manager_id will work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements of your particular application, a more efficient solution might be to create a function based index:

```
CREATE INDEX emp_start_letter_idx
    ON employees ( substr( last_name, 1, 1 ) );
```

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT last_name
FROM employees
WHERE substr(last_name, 1, 1) = '&Start_Letter';
```

Likewise, depending on your requirements, this may be a lot of unnecessary fuss!

Comment: Unnecessary fuss then, kind of what I thought. Glad it was of interest anyway. Something to think about if you're ever dealing with lots of records and lots of users. :)